# How to handle long path with spaces in Windows with Python

Tags: python, whitespace, filepath

In the following code, I need to iterate through files in a directory with long names and spaces in paths.

```
def avg_dmg_acc(path):
    for d in os.listdir(path):
        sub_path = path + '/' + d
        if os.path.isdir(sub_path):
            if d.startswith('Front'):
                for f in os.listdir(sub_path):
                    fpath = r"%s" % sub_path + '/' + f
                    print(fpath)
                    print(os.path.exists(fpath))
                    df = pd.read_csv(fpath)
```

Then I ran the function providing the argument `path`:

```
path = r"./Mid-Con Master dd3d5c56-581c-42e0-acde-04e7feed3bb8/620138 91852327-e08d-4ed1-9774-383c888cb04e/Power End 2d41ba63-dfb9-4984-a5a5-153997fea43a"
avg_dmg_acc(path)
```

However I am getting file not exist error:

```
File b'./Mid-Con Master dd3d5c56-581c-42e0-acde-04e7feed3bb8/620138 91852327-e08d-4ed1-9774-383c888cb04e/Power End 2d41ba63-dfb9-4984-a5a5-153997fea43a/Front c41f42ce-7158-4371-8cf6-82d1bcf04787/Damage Accumulation f907a97a-6d2d-40f6-ba02-0bc0599b773b.csv' does not exist
```

As you can see, I am already using `r"path"` since I read it somewhere it handles spaces in path. Also the path was constructed manually in this version, e.g. `sub_path = path + '/' + d` but I tried to use `os.path.join(path, d)` originally and it didn't work. I also tried `Path` from `pathlib` since it is  [the recommended way in Python 3](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f) and still the same. At one point I tried to use `os.path.abspath` instead of the relative path I am using now with `./` but it still says file not exist.

Why is it not working? Is it because the path is too long or spaces are still not dealt with correctly?

Comment: There could be an number of reasons.  I would suggest printing `pathlib.Path(sub_path).resolve().exists()` first to test if they exist.  If not, the input string is somehow wrong.  Print them and update your findings.

Comment: How can your code produce that error?

Comment: @PeterWood I got the error from `pd.read_csv`. Post edited.

Comment: @pylang `sub_path` is fine. It shows it exists. It is the `fpath`. `Path(fpath).resolve().exists` returns false.

Comment: consider `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is the length of the path that is causing this problem. I tried to reduce the folder name of the lowest level one character at a time and got to the point where `os.path.exists(fpath)` changed from `false` to `true`. I think I will need to rename all the folder names before processing

Comment: Try Lupas Rename 2000 to batch rename.  I'd switch everything to pathlib if I were you.

Comment: @pylang As you can see every folder has a long guid at the end. Is this Lupas thing smart enough to rename based on this logic?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It can do a lot, but only what you tell it.